# Android back key does nothing?

Tags: java, android

My app consists of one activity. When i press back nothing happens, why is this? I thought it would kill the app. If I press home the app contines in the background as desired. It's just the back button that does nothing. What could I have done to affect this?

I have read in the documentation:

```
public void onBackPressed ()
```

Called when the activity has **detected the user's press of the back key**.
The default implementation simply finishes the **current activity** but you can override this to do whatever you want.

I have not overridden this.

Here is something that has been mentioned, overriding keys:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event == null || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        return false;
    }
   if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){

    mEntry.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v,boolean hasFocus){
              /* When focus is lost check that the text field
               * has valid values.
               */
              if (!hasFocus && !mEntry.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {

                    mSession.appendToEmulator(cmdLeft, 0, cmdLeft.length);
                    mSession.appendToEmulator(cmdErase, 0, cmdErase.length);

                    Log.d(TAG, "in inner delete");
              }
              else {mEntry.setText(" ");
              }
        }          
    });


    Log.d(TAG, "in delete in delete in delete in delete");
    try {
        sendOverSerial("\b".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
};
```

Another snippet,  from onCreate:

```
mEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.term_entry);

        mEntry.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {

                /* Ignore enter-key-up events. */
                if (event != null && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: if we don't see your code, we can't find that out neither ;)

Comment: yes you should override it and if you are in main activity android os back button itself finish the activity

Comment: Well the code is a few thousand lines, I'm just wondering what ways do you know of that could have affected this? I suppose I can override it and make it finish, but it should already be doing that.

Comment: what do you want to perform on that??

Comment: I don't understand your question shiv.

Comment: What version of Android are you targetting? If you're on old versions (pre 2.0) you might be overriding it with OnKeyDown

Comment: i mean you are finishing the activity on backpressed why? android os itself provide you with that option na??

Comment: targeting sdk12. The only thing I can think of with keys is that I override the delete key with dispatchKeyEvent.

Comment: On backpress what operation you need to perform..

Comment: Shiv, yes it should be closing the app when i press the back key by default, but it is not.

Comment: why this topic is with vote level 3 ??

Comment: @Janmejoy it should be performing the default action, finishing the current activity.

Comment: see this example @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

  this.finish();
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
  return;
 }  in this i have finished the current activity and perform sliding also and both works fine

Comment: finish the current and move to previous ..am i right..

Comment: I will try that thanks shiv. @Janmejoy yes, but if the current is the launcher it should close the app and go to the home screen

Comment: What would happen if you override onBackPressed, log out something so you know it is actually called and then do super.onBackPressed?

Comment: thanks will try these suggestions, just going for lunch first. Thanks.

Comment: first suggestion you should follow is bofredo's offer.

Comment: @Paul did you check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without your actual code it is diffucult to say, but I'll take a bold guess and say that somewhere in your `Activity` you have overridden `onKeyDown` or `onKeyUp` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` is handled there. I experienced the behaviour in my own app that if `onKeyDown` handles the back-key and returns `true`, `onBackPressed()` will never even get called.

Comment: I have been messing with keyEvents and I put up the code I have dealing with them.

Comment: Hmm, you haven't overridden the back key anywhere I can see. Have you tries explicitly calling `super.onBackPressed` when the back key is pressed in `dispatchKeyEvent`?

Comment: No I haven't tried that, I only handled delete in there. I just tried the answer below but the method is never called. I'll try that now thanks.

Comment: This worked, I wasn't handling KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK in there, just delete, so if you handle anything it must mess with the back key which is odd. I now specifically handle the back key

Comment: Your answer is still helpful in 2020. Thanks for that!